# Find points $A$ and $B$ on the parabola $y=1-x^2$ such that an equilateral triangle is formed by the $x$-axis and the tangents $A$ and $B$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, triangles, conic-sections, tangent-line

**Question**

> Using Calculus, find points $A$ and $B$ on the parabola $y=1-x^2$ such that an equilateral triangle is formed by the $x$-axis and the tangents $A$ and $B$.

If I'm not mistaken, I think it would look roughly something like this.

[image]

Comment: What would the value of $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ be? (Draw a picture.)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The tangent line at point $x_0$ is given by:
$$xf'(x_0)+b=0$$
or
$$x\tan \alpha + b = 0 $$
where $\alpha$ is an angle between the line and x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Using your diagram, the $x$-intercepts would be $(-c,0)$ and $(c, 0)$, the $y$-intercept would be $(0,c\sqrt3)$ (Pythagorean theorem).  We don't care what $c$ is.

$y'=-2x = \frac {a\sqrt3-0} {0-a} =-\sqrt3$ (slope of hypotenuse of right triangle on the right), so $x = \frac{\sqrt3} 2$.

then $y = 1 - (\frac{\sqrt 3} 2)^2 = \frac 1 4$.

So: $B(\frac{\sqrt 3} 2, \frac 1 4)$.  By symmetry or using the same process, $A(-\frac{\sqrt 3} 2, \frac 1 4)$.